# if A is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then there exists $B\subset A$ dense and countable in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I found this result in so many books and I tried to demonstrate it but I'm not convinced with my proof,

if A is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then there exists $B\subset A$  dense and countable in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:** What happens if you remove a single point from $A$? Or any finite number of points from $A$?

Comment: I guess not a big change since A is dense

Comment: But can you prove it?

Comment: I don't have a rigorous demonstration but I thought to take $B=A\cap \mathbb{Q}$ !!

Comment: And what if $A\subseteq\Bbb Q$? Or what if $A\cap\Bbb Q=\varnothing$?

Comment: oh! you're right, but then we can choose $B=A\cap \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ can we ?

Comment: But what if $A=\Bbb Q$? Then $B=\varnothing$. In general, there are countable dense sets which are far strangers than you can imagine. It's best to try and come up with a general method, and not ad hoc intersections.

Comment: okay, that's what it seems to me.

Comment: For that matter, take $B=A$. Usually "$\subset$" does not mean "$\subsetneq$", but some have different conventions in that regard.

Comment: @MPW: If you allow equality then this entire question doesn't make *any* sense.

Comment: Of course it does. In fact, it's included in your answer, isn't it? Wouldn't you say that zero points is a finite number of points?

Comment: @MPW: Wow, have you ever heard the term "context" before?

Answer (score 4):

With some care you can find an infinite and co-infinite subset of $A$ which is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

1. Enumerate the open intervals with rational endpoints as $\{ I_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.
2. Inductively pick for each $n$ distinct $a_n, b_n \in (A \cap I_n) \setminus \{ a_i , b_i : i < n \}$. (For this note that $I_n \cap A$ is infinite for all $n$.)
3. Consider $B = \{ b_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Comment: thanks for this procedure, but I was wonder what if we found that for a $n$ we found that $A \cap I_n$

Comment: @houda, your above comment seems to be incomplete. If you meant to ask "...we found that $A \cap I_n \neq \varnothing$, note that this is impossible, since a dense set has nonempty intersection with _every_ nonempty open set.

Comment: oh! I didn't pay attention to that, coming back to your method I honestly can't figure out how to prove that B is dense. Can you please give me an indication ?

Comment: @houda: Can you show that $B$ has nonempty intersection with every nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$?